# how card.io convert credit card image to clean binary image without any noise

Tags: image, opencv, ocr

dose any one know how card.ioeprocess the image and remove the non-text background without noise. I'm making a credit card ocr engine like card.io. But it is very tough to remove the non-text background without any noise. thus, it cannot send to NN to make further process.
So dose any have experience on this kind of problem.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Jin,
You can check Card Scanning Solutions http://www.card-reader.com/ they have developped OCR for many kinds of cards, including those whith non-text background.

Comment: thanks johnbarr, I have visit this website, but I think their solution is not suitable for credit card ocr. because credit card has complex background and embossed text.